# I published a python package called virtualp successfully. But when I'm installing the package it is throwing error

Tags: python, package, pypi

**This is the error**

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting virtualp
Using cached virtualp-0.0.1.tar.gz (2.1 kB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;           sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SANTOS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kkg3ajy_\\virtualp\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SANTOS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kkg3ajy_\\virtualp\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\SANTOS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_kzh3r8q'
     cwd: C:\Users\SANTOS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kkg3ajy_\virtualp\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\SANTOS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kkg3ajy_\virtualp\setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    long_description=open('README.txt').read() + '\n\n' + open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHANGELOG.txt'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full    command output.
```

*I use this command to install the package--> python -m pip install virtualp *

*This is the setup.py file*

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
classifiers = [
  'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
  'Intended Audience :: Education',
  'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10',
  'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
  'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
]

setup(
  name='virtualp',
  version='0.0.1',
  description='you can use for Virtual Paints',
  long_description=open('README.txt').read() + '\n\n' + open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
  url='',  
  author='Santosh Burada',
  author_email='santu.burada99@gmail.com',
  license='MIT', 
  classifiers=classifiers,
  keywords='computer-vision', 
  packages=find_packages(),
  package_data={'virtualp': ['CHANGELOG.txt', 'README.txt']},
  install_requires=['opencv-python', 'numpy'] 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `package_data` in your call to `setup()` in `setup.py`. Without it, no non-`.py` files will be included in your package. You can find details [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files), but it should probably look something like

```py
setup(
    ...
    package_data={'virtualp': ['CHANGELOG.txt', 'README.txt']}
)
```

Comment: if I add this to setup it will work, once see the edits I included my setup.py file